# Is 1/5 of studies that use 80% power calculations wrong?

Tags: statistical-power

I'm just learning about power calculations. As I understood, the most commonly used power is 80%, meaning that if there is an effect, the null hypothesis is rejected in 80% of the cases. However, I'm puzzled by the large margin of error. It seems to me that this leads to 20% of studies using 80% power calculations failing to reject the null hypothesis. Do 20% of these studies suffer from type II error? I can't imagine this being acceptable academic practice. Am I missing something?

Comment: You seem to mischaracterize power.  In particular, power depends on the *size* of the effect, not just on whether there is a nonzero effect.